# How to add a high score using swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am developing a game with swift in Xcode 6. But I can not figure out how I'm adding a high score, it's the only thing I need to add to the game. I have tried to follow some answers in here.

I've added a new swift file called HighScore.swift and in it I inserted the following code:

```
import Foundation

class HighScore: NSObject {

    var highScore: Int = 0

    func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder!) {
        aCoder.encodeInteger(highScore, forKey: "highScore")
    }

    init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder!) {
        highScore = aDecoder.decodeIntegerForKey("highScore")
    }

    override init() {
    }
}

class SaveHighScore:NSObject {

    var documentDirectories:NSArray = []
    var documentDirectory:String = ""
    var path:String = ""

    func ArchiveHighScore(#highScore: HighScore) {
        documentDirectories = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)
        documentDirectory = documentDirectories.objectAtIndex(0) as String
        path = documentDirectory.stringByAppendingPathComponent("highScore.archive")

        if NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(highScore, toFile: path) {
            println("Success writing to file!")
        } else {
            println("Unable to write to file!")
        }
} }
```

And I have created a new file `GameViewController.swift`and inserted this code in class Game View Controller: UIViewController:

```
class View Controller: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
         were Score = High Score ()

         override viewDidLoad func () {
             super.viewDidLoad ()

             Score.highScore = 100
             Save High Score (). Archive High Score (high score: Score)
             was retrievedHighScore = Save High Score (). RetrieveHighScore () as High Score
             System.out.println (retrievedHighScore.highScore)

         }
     }
```

But then i get this fault:
`SaveHighScore does not have a member named`RetriveHighScore`

Can some help me with this?

Sorry for my bad English.

Sincerely,
HH

Comment: I don't want to be rude, but there are to many errors in your code. I don't know how you can even build your app. You have to resolve all the errors before we can help you. But the SaveHighScore isn't your main problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, can you please tell me what i am doing wrong? SaveHighScore is the only problem xcode find. How can i create a high score in a good way?

Comment: Am I right, that you have copied the other parts of your game from a tutorial? If that's the case, I'd highly recommend to learn some basics, before you try this. Because if we help you now, you won't learn anything, because you don't understand the actual code you are using.

Comment: I have developed the rest of the code, it is not the best game anytime, it's just because I want to learn it. I've put myself into the basics, but I'm about to stire me blind to the problem here. For the high score I have found code on the net from tutorials, yes.

Comment: Check my answer. But like Martin said, it's hard to believe that you've copied it. Have you altered it?

Comment: Looks like the code from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25985450/saving-highscores-with-nsuserdefaults?lq=1 but it got messed up...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Am I right, that you have copied the other parts of your game from a tutorial?

If that's the case, I'd highly recommend to learn some basics, before you try this. You are using things like `System.out.println` which is clearly Java code.

I know that feeling. You see other games in the app store and want to build one by yourself.(maybe the next Flappy Bird). But you have to start slow and really [learn the basics.](https://www.google.ch/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.raywenderlich.com%2F74438%2Fswift-tutorial-a-quick-start&ei=s-_PVLTtHIT6UPi6guAF&usg=AFQjCNEr_BDty_ZNTHgZYZc0bYlwlB46SQ&sig2=vWI9QTcXwgsLlyMmR_D2hA&bvm=bv.85076809,d.bGQ)

Because there are some errors like spaces in variables, using `was` or `were` instead of `var` etc. These are the basics you need to know. So I'd recommend you that you learn from basic-tutorials before.

But I will resolve the errors for you so that you have non-error code. But I don't if you can make it to work, because there is code, I don't understand why you have it in there.

**important**:
The code doesn't work and will not work. I've tried to resolve as many errors as possible, but it's impossible to make it work, because you call methods which aren't implemented anywhere in you classes.

```
import UIKit

//ViewController has to be written together without spaces
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
    //use always var and not were and use lowercase variables
    var score = HighScore()

    //not override viewDidLoad func
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad ()

        score.highScore = 100
        //create an instance of your SaveHighscore class
        var saveHighscore = SaveHighScore()
        //why the spaces?? add the score and not (high score: Score) that's how you write it in the function
        saveHighscore.ArchiveHighScore(score)

        //again var and not was
        //There is no function "RetrieveHighScore" so this line isn't possible
        var retrievedHighScore = Save High Score ().RetrieveHighScore () as HighScore

        //System.out.println is Java
        System.out.println (retrievedHighScore.highScore)

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have been trying to follow this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25985450/saving-highscores-with-nsuserdefaults

Comment: I would highly recommend you to do this tutorial first: http://www.raywenderlich.com/74438/swift-tutorial-a-quick-start 
And later you can try to make a game with this tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/84434/sprite-kit-swift-tutorial-beginners

Comment: You are welcome. Don't get me wrong. Everybody has started once. :) If my answer helped you, please accept my answer by clicking on the tick on the left side of my answer so that other people also can find my answer better.

Comment: I think you are right, I will slow down and learn the basics 110% :-)
I think I have accept your answer, right? :-)

Comment: If you've got any questions which won't fit in the Q/A scheme of StackOverflow, feel free to ask via twitter(@cwoerz).